# I'm trying to use pyplot.scatter() but I'm getting an invalid syntax error

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I'm trying to use pyplot.scatter() but I'm getting the following error:

```
 plt.scatter(y=temperature_planet,x=t,s=2, color="red")
   ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can see the issue is on the last line of the code. I'm not sure what's going on

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import time
import decimal

t = 0
temperature_planet = 200
temperature_atmosphere = 250

epsilon = decimal.Decimal(0.25)
dt = 60*10
heat_capacity = decimal.Decimal(1E5)
insolation = decimal.Decimal(1370)
sigma = decimal.Decimal(5.67E-8)
planet_radius = decimal.Decimal(6.4E6)

circle = decimal.Decimal(np.pi)*planet_radius**decimal.Decimal(2.0)
sphere = 4*decimal.Decimal(np.pi)*planet_radius**decimal.Decimal(2.0)


plt.scatter(y=temperature_planet,x=t,s=2, color="red")
plt.ion()
plt.xlabel("Time (S)")
plt.ylabel("Temperature (K)")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

print(temperature_planet)
while True:
   temperature_planet += dt*(circle*insolation + sphere* epsilon*sigma* 
   temperature_atmosphere**decimal.Decimal(4.0) - 
   sphere*sigma*temperature_planet**decimal.Decimal(4.0)/heat_capacity
   t += dt
   plt.scatter(y=temperature_planet,x=t)
   plt.pause(0.005)
   time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `)` at the end of the previous line

Answer (score 0):

Check second last line sphere = 4*(np.pi*planet_radius**2.0

The Parenthesis are missing at the end.

Comment: I changed my code to look as it does now, but now I get an issue with 
t += dt. where the error is: invalid syntax